# ngfor safari angular showing no elements IOS 11.1.1

Tags: ios, angular, ngfor, polyfills

I added the below polyfills. However no luck on safari, it works fine on chrome. 
The angular material form and animation works if I delete *ngfor from HTML 
I am using angular 4.2.4
I read some posts where the advise is given to add the following:

```
 <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js? 
  features=Intl.~locale.en"></script>
```

Before the other libraries, however as I am quite new to angular and MEAN NODE js I am  not sure where I am supposed to add this line.
I added it on the HTML page (this didn't do anything, didn't give any errors nor did it solve the issue) 
I will try it with a seprate js file, however I am afraid this is not going to work. Any ideas?

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'web-animations-js';
import 'intl';
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';
```

my HTML file

```
 <mat-form-field *ngFor="let key of arrayOfKeys" 
 class="halffull-width-
 input">
 <input id ="coin"  
 class="form-control" 
    matInput placeholder="Write Coin Name" 
    [(ngModel)]="key.coin" 
    formControlName="coin" required>
```